# getting a warning setting up delegate for a custom protocol

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6

i added a custom protocol to one of my classes and i am getting a compiler warning when i attempt to set the delegate during a prepareForSegue: method. the warning i get is...

```
Sending 'MyCustomViewControllerClass *const __strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<NSFileManagerDelegate>'
```

the project builds and runs and everything works fine minus the warning. if i add `<NSFileManagerDelegate>` to my custom class the warning goes away. am i missing something or is this a bug in Xcode (6 beta)? the code is standard code for setting up a protocol / delegate but i will post it anyways...

SomeSecondClass.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit>

@class SomeSecondCustomViewController;

@protocol SomeSecondCustomViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)doThisForMe
@end

@interface SomeSecondCustomViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) id <SomeSecondCustomViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

SomeSecondClass.m

```
@interface SomeSecondViewController ()
…stuff

-(void)someMethod {

    [self.delegate doThisForMe];
}

@end
```

CustomClass.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import “ SomeSecondViewController.h”

@interface MyCustomViewController : UIViewController <SomeSecondCustomViewControllerDelegate>
//adding on <NSFileManagerDelegate> removes the warning...
@end
```

CustomClass.h

```
...standard stuff...

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"MySegue"]) {

         //this is where the warning happens on "self"
         [segue.destinationViewController setDelegate:self];

    }
}


- (void)doThisForMe {

   //doing some stuff...

}
@end
```

i have opened previous projects where the warning did not exist and now the same warning appears. i am wondering if this is an Xcode problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are running into an issue caused by an ambiguity in how Objective-C finds a matching selector and dealing with an `id` reference.

`UIStoryboardSegue destinationViewController` returns an `id`. Your code then tries to call the `setDelegate` method on this `id` reference. Since there is no information about what this `id` actually references, it doesn't know which `setDelegate:` method you might mean (there are many). So the compiler scans through the list it knows of and picks one. In this case it chose the `setDelegate:` method from the `NSFileManager` class. Since `self` doesn't conform to the `NSFileManagerDelegate` protocol, you get the warning.

You could ignore the warning and your code will work fine in this case.

The better solution is to help the compiler by adding a cast:

```
[(SomeSecondCustomViewController *)segue.destinationViewController setDelegate:self];
```

This will let the compiler know which `setDelegate:` method you really mean.

BTW - Adding `NSFileManagerDelegate` to your class is not a valid solution even if it works at the moment. A simple reordering of some `import` statements could lead the compiler to make a different choice and your warning would return but complain about not conforming to some other protocol.

Comment: just for anyone skimming, this is a complier change in Xcode 6 for Swift compatibility. moving forward Swift will be expecting the "as" type for setting delegates. this is the same as casting as stated above. my guess is thats why the warning is only occurring in Xcode 6.

Answer (score 1):

as it turns out, this is a bug / change in Xcode 6 beta. running this exact same code on Xcode 5.1.1 produces no warnings or errors. the problem is cause because in Xcode 6 the compiler is asking for type

```
(id<NSFileManager>)
```

for the delegate. in Xcode 5.1 the compiler is simply expecting

```
(id)
```

for the delegate type.

as rmaddy stated, by casting the type in

```
[(SomeSecondCustomViewController *)segue.destinationViewController setDelegate:self];
```

it did remove the warning, but this should be an unnecessary step and will chalk it up to a problem with Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly typing (giving type to) the destinationVC, like this:

```
SomeSecondCustomViewController *vc = (SomeSecondCustomViewController  *)segue.destinationViewController;
vc.delegate = self;
```

Comment: i've done that, and it also removes the warning but should be an unnecessary step during prepareForSegue: as that processes should already be done for you. i've never gotten this error in Xcode 5 before which is throwing me for a loop.

Answer (score 0):

@rmaddy provides the correct answer. This is a more detailed example for those of us who are lightly schooled in the ways of Objective-C.

I changed my code from:

```
    [[segue destinationViewController] setDelegate:self];
    UIPopoverController *popoverController = [(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue popoverController];
    self.flipsidePopoverController = popoverController;
    popoverController.delegate = self;
```

to:

```
    [(UIPopoverController *)segue.destinationViewController setDelegate:self];
    UIPopoverController *popoverController = [(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue popoverController];
    self.flipsidePopoverController = popoverController;
    popoverController.delegate = self;
```

and the warnings disappeared.