# xcode 6 Beta - strange warning for ViewPort delegates

Tags: xcode, delegates, warnings, viewcontroller

One of the example projects in XCode 5 was named "Utility Application". It  had a main view and an alternate view and set up an Info button to flip the main view to the alternate view. It used a viewcontroller delegate and a protocol definition to switch back from the flip view to the main view. In XCode 6 it is no longer there.

When I run this simple XCode 5 example app in XCode 6, I get a warning in the method below:

```
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showAlternate"]) {
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDelegate:self]; //<<<< Here is where the warning appears
    }
}
```

The warning is: **Sending 'MainViewController *const_strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id'**

What is this? A bug? The app runs fine on both simulator and iOS device.  Below is the entire code. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
**//  MainViewController.h

#import "FlipsideViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate>

@end

//  MainViewController.m

#import "MainViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController ()

@end

@implementation MainViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Flipside View

- (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(FlipsideViewController *)controller
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showAlternate"]) {
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDelegate:self]; //<<<< Here is where the warning appears
    }
}

@end


//  FlipsideViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class FlipsideViewController;

@protocol FlipsideViewControllerDelegate
- (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(FlipsideViewController *)controller;
@end

@interface FlipsideViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) id <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

- (IBAction)done:(id)sender;

@end


//  FlipsideViewController.m

#import "FlipsideViewController.h"

@interface FlipsideViewController ()

@end

@implementation FlipsideViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Actions

- (IBAction)done:(id)sender
{
    [self.delegate flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:self];
}

@end**
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have figured this out already...just wanted to post a link for for those stumbling upon this: [getting a warning setting up delegate for a custom protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24248825/getting-a-warning-setting-up-delegate-for-a-custom-protocol)